# C signal parent process from child

Tags: c, unix, process

I'm trying to solve a problem I've got where a child process runs execvp() and needs to let the parent know if it returns. So, after the execvp() returns (because there's been an error), how can I tell the parent that this particular event has happened so it can handle it.

There's one method of writing a string of text through the pipe I'm using and then reading that from the parent.. but it seems a bit sloppy. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Edit: Here is some code I'm trying where I can't seem to get the read to return.

```
int errorPipe[2];
signal( SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN );

int oldflags = fcntl (errorPipe[0], F_GETFD, 0);
oldflags |= FD_CLOEXEC;
fcntl (errorPipe[0], F_SETFD, oldflags);
oldflags = fcntl (errorPipe[1], F_GETFD, 0);
oldflags |= FD_CLOEXEC;
fcntl (errorPipe[1], F_SETFD, oldflags);

pipe( errorPipe );

// in the child..
char *error_message = "exec failed";
write( errorPipe[1], error_message, strlen(error_message)+1 );
exit(-1);

// in the parent
printf("read gives: %d\n", read(errorPipe[0], error_read, MAX_LINE_LENGTH) );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is a pipe with the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag set, as then you can detect a successful exec as easily as a failure. In the event of a failure, I'd write whole the error message back to the parent over the pipe, but you could just write the status code or anything else that is meaningful. (Definitely write *something* though; nothing written has got to be a sign of a successful start of the other executable.)

[EDIT]: How to make use of this:

If the parent needs to wait until it knows whether the child successfully ran `execve()` (the unlying syscall) then it should do a blocking `read()` on the pipe. A zero result from that indicates success. (Make sure you've got `SIGPIPE` ignored.)

If the parent has some kind of event handling framework based on non-blocking IO and `select()` (or `poll()` or `kqueue()` or …) then wait for the pipe to become readable before trying to read the message (which will be zero-length if the child did the `execve()` correctly).

Comment: Somewhat hack-ish but pretty elegant. Not always possible, but +1 from me anyway.

Comment: Yep, elegant and actually answers the question.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the questioner was already almost on top of the solution. And no, I don't know of a more elegant way; detecting success is the hard part, and I do know that the trick with a pipe is used in some production libraries.

Comment: thanks - this is very helpful :) just wondering though, what would be the best way to check if the pipe is closed in my parent? I could do a read from it, but if the pipe is open I would discard data that I want to get later.

Comment: @Gary: You can't check if the pipe is open as such. All you can do is wait (in one of the ways described in my edit) until something happens, at which point you've got to deal with it. Keep your message short in the error case (and don't use the pipe for anything else!) and you should be able to have either a complete read of an error message, or a zero-length read for success.

Comment: I've tried to do what you've said but read is still not returning when there is no error - can you take a look back at the top?

Comment: @Gary: You need to set *both* ends of the pipe to be `CLOEXEC`, not just the end you're reading from.

Comment: that didn't seem to do it yet. updated code is above. any other ideas?

Comment: No. I've checked against some production code that does this sort of thing, and that does exactly what I described.

Comment: Solved it - turned out that I needed to close the other end of the errorPipe not being used in the child & parent. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`execvp`() never returns, except when it fails to even start the executable at all. If it can start the executable, it will not return, no matter what the executable does (i.e. regardless to whether the executable succeeds at its task or not).

Your parent process will receive a `SIGCHLD` signal, for which you can install a signal handler.

Or you can `wait`(2) for the child process.

```
int child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0) {
    execvp("/path/to/executable", ...);
    exit(123); /* this happens only if execvp() fails to invoke executable */
}

/* ... */

int status = 0;
int exit_pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
if (exit_pid == child_pid && WIFEXITED(status)) {
    if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0) {
        /* child process exited fine */
    } else if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 123)
        /* execvp() itself failed */
    } else {
        /* executed child process failed */
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm well aware that execvp() never returns when it is successful. I want to handle *only* the case that execvp fails. Not if a process runs and then exits.

Comment: exit() with a non-zero return code, as you will have to check the return code of the child in any case, i.e. also when execvp() works.

Comment: what if another process could exit with that code? how will the parent tell the difference though?

Comment: The parent needs to know the child process ID, as returned by fork() to the parent process. waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) checks if any child process has terminated, and returns its PID or 0 if no child process has terminated. The exit status (if any) will be written into int status. See man 2 wait for details.

Answer (score 0):

Cache the pid for the (child) process for which you want to examine the status in the parent. 
Add a handler for SIGCHLD in the parent. In the child call exit with some status value of your choosing to denote that execvp failed.   On receiving the signal in the parent you now have 2 options
a) Call waitpid with a pid of -1 (i.e. wait for any child), examine the return value, if that matches your cached pid, examine the status using macros like WEXITSTATUS.
b) Call waitpid with your cached pid , then on return examine the exit status.

To make this robust you should call WIFEXITED(status) before examining the exit status via WEXITSTATUS. WIFEXITED returns true if the child terminated normally i.e. by calling exit or _exit and not as a result of seg fault, un handled signal etc.
Also see man wait(2).